# Creating trees in beamer

Tags: beamer, forest

I am trying to create a tree in `beamer` with `forest`.  Adding long text moves the contents out of the frame. Can someone help?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\colorlet{ProcessBlue}{blue!50!cyan}
\tikzset{
  selected/.style={draw=ProcessBlue, thick, rounded corners=2pt, inner color=ProcessBlue!25, outer color=ProcessBlue!35, drop shadow,}
}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{hide on/.code={\only<#1>{\color{white}}}}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\subsection{frame 2}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=west,
    anchor=west,
    selected,
    grow=-45,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, thick, -{Stealth[]}, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      if level=0{}{
        content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={#1. #2}{level()}{content()},
      },
    },
  }
  [\LaTeX
    [TestTest
      [StartTestStartTestStartTestStartTest
        [DoTest
          [MakeTest
            [TestTest
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is the link[https://www.sharelatex.com/read/yhsvqfxzfgbv
] to the sharelatex project, [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237359/latex-tree-diagram-inserting-arrows)

Comment: Why do you don't use the`shrink` option in the frame environment? Something like `\begin{frame}[fragile,shrink=20]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, `shrink` works. But, the lines that originate from each node is varying in length. I would like to set all the lines to equal length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me thinks you got that code from somebody else who you've failed to acknowledge. The link would be appreciated; attribution is no more than courtesy requires and might be useful, too.

In any case, you really don't want to use `grow=45` here. The content of your nodes is sometimes long and varies wildly. The result is predictably problematic.

Why not just use the built-in `folder` style?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\colorlet{ProcessBlue}{blue!50!cyan}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
  selected/.style={draw=ProcessBlue, thick, rounded corners=2pt, inner color=ProcessBlue!25, outer color=ProcessBlue!35, drop shadow,},
}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\subsection{frame 2}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{forest}
    folder indent'+=10pt,
    for tree={
      folder,
      grow'=0,
      l sep'+=20pt,
      s sep'+=10pt,
      selected,
      font=\sffamily,
      edge+={thick, -{Stealth[]}},
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        if level=0{}{
          content/.process={OOw2{level}{content}{#1. #2}},
        },
      },
    }
    [\LaTeX
      [TestTest
        [StartTestStartTestStartTestStartTest
          [DoTest
            [MakeTest
              [TestTest
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: reformatted tree]

By the way, making the text white is not a good way to hide content in a Beamer presentation! There are a bunch of specially adapted styles around for this already and you would be much better to use those. (There are even some specifically for Forest trees.)

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by `hiding content`

Comment: @Natasha What do you use `hide on` for if not hiding stuff? Please don't use code tags for quotes - it screws things up for anybody using a screen reader (which will spell out what you quoted rather than saying the words).

Comment: @Natasha What cft are tring to say is that it is possible to create dynamical effect in Beamer's presentations simply using `\onslide<num>{_text_}`, `\visible<num>{_text_}` and stuff like that, see the [beamerguide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). For an example of the effects that can be achieved you can watch my YouTube video (in italian language) of the [Airy's demostration of the Pitagora's theorem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXAqVJCt7aI).

Comment: @vipa Not really. The default macros are not of much direct use here. However, there is code based on those macros which does the job. In particular, it utilises `\alt` extensively. This is the basis for Ti*k*Z and Forest styles and is what is wanted here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the *forest* package, but it's very easy to make a tree like yours with *tikz* only.
A very simple code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=25]
\frametitle{Test}
\colorlet{ProcessBlue}{blue!50!cyan}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=2mm,
ar/.style={->,>=stealth,thick},
every node/.style={rectangle,rounded corners=2pt,
drop shadow,draw=ProcessBlue,fill=ProcessBlue!35,thick,
node distance=1.2cm %vertical distance
}]
%leaf
\node (n0)                                  {\LaTeX};
\node (n1)      [below = of n0,xshift=9ex]   {1. TestTest};
\node (n2)      [below = of n1,xshift=23ex]   {2.StartTestStartTestStartTestStartTest};
\node (n3)      [below = of n2,xshift=18ex]    {3. DoTest};
\node (n4)      [below = of n3,xshift=12ex]     {4. MakeTest};
\node (n5)      [below = of n4,xshift=12ex]      {5.TestTest};
%arrows
\foreach \ns/\ne in{0/1,1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5}
\draw[ar] (n\ns) |- (n\ne);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

the vertical distance between all the "leafs" of the tree is controlled by `node distance` and the horizontal distance between a single leaf and the leaf immediatly above by `xshift`.
The result is
[image]