# Arranging the nodes of tree in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am trying to create a tree in `beamer` with `forest`. The lines between two adjacent nodes are unequally spaced. Can someone help?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\colorlet{ProcessBlue}{blue!50!cyan}
\tikzset{
  selected/.style={draw=ProcessBlue, thick, rounded corners=2pt, inner color=ProcessBlue!25, outer color=ProcessBlue!35, drop shadow,}
}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{hide on/.code={\only<#1>{\color{white}}}}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\subsection{frame 2}
\begin{frame}[fragile,shrink=20]
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=west,
    anchor=west,
    selected,
    grow=-45,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, thick, -{Stealth[]}, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={
      if level=0{}{
        content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={#1. #2}{level()}{content()},
      },
    },
  }
  [\LaTeX
    [TestTest
      [StartTestStartTestStartTestStartTest
        [DoTest
          [MakeTest
            [TestTest
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you be so kind and explain the difference between this question and your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429821/121799), which @cfr gave a really good answer to (and which you probably forgot to accept)? BTW, @cfr was referring to `\tikzset{hide on/.code={\only<#1>{\color{white}}}}`, I think. Type `texdoc aobs` for further information.

Comment: This question was about arranging the lines between adjacent nodes. Many a time I have been advised to create a new post and not to extend questions in the same post.Therefore, I created a new post. Thanks! P.S. I have accepted the answer

Comment: No worries! But it would be really nice if you would refer to previous questions and/or the source of your code(s) such that people (and cute furry rodents and marmots) would know which options you have already explored and/or you already are familiar with. This is all to your advantage.

Comment: I will definitely stick to these guidelines in all my future queries:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is triggered by the `grow=-45` directive. If you want to keep the distances constant, you may want to work with the `l` and `s` keys instead.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\colorlet{ProcessBlue}{blue!50!cyan}
\tikzset{
  selected/.style={draw=ProcessBlue, thick, rounded corners=2pt, inner color=ProcessBlue!25, outer color=ProcessBlue!35, drop shadow,}
}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\tikzset{hide on/.code={\only<#1>{\color{white}}}}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\subsection{frame 2}
\begin{frame}[fragile,shrink=20]
\begin{forest}
  for tree={l=1.2cm,s=1.2cm,
    parent anchor=south west,
    child anchor=west,
    anchor=west,
    selected,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, thick, -{Stealth[]}, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) |- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  },
  before typesetting nodes={
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles,
      if level=0{}{
        content/.wrap 2 pgfmath args={#1. #2}{level()}{content()},
      },
    }
  }
  [\LaTeX
    [TestTest
      [StartTestStartTestStartTestStartTest,l sep=0
        [DoTest
          [MakeTest
            [TestTest
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]